# Mixing values in `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` query

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Say I want to insert a comment, the comments table needs a `customer_id` but I only have `email`. I do not want to select the customer in a separate query beforehand.

The `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` query from [orm/query-builder.html#inserting-data](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/query-builder.html#inserting-data) looks like what I want exactly.

But how do I provide values outside of what gets selected in the first part of the query?

1. I tried:

   ```
    $select = $customersTable->find()
        ->select(['customer_id'])
        ->where(['email' => 'username@example.com']);
    $query = $this->query()
        ->insert(['customer_id', 'data'])
        ->values($select)
        ->values(['data' => 'test 123'])
        ->execute();
   ```

   I got: *You cannot mix subqueries and array data in inserts*
2. I tried:

   ```
    $select = $customersTable->find()
        ->select(['customer_id', '"test" AS `data`'])
        ->where(['email' => 'username@example']);
    $query = $this->query()
        ->insert(['customer_id', 'data'])
        ->values($select)
        ->execute();
   ```

   I got:

   ```
   Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`` AS `Customers__"test" AS `data`` FROM `customer` `Customers` ' at line 1

   INSERT INTO `comments` (`customer_id`, `data`) SELECT `Customers`.`customer_id` AS `Customers__customer_id`, `Customers."test" AS `data`` AS `Customers__"test" AS `data`` FROM `customer` `Customers` WHERE `email` = :c0
   ```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom aliased fields in the `SELECT` clause can be defined via the regular `key => value` array syntax, where the key will be used as the alias.

Also make sure to let the driver quote the data, as it will be inserted as-is, and thus would otherwise be prone to possible SQL injections!

```php
$select = $customersTable->find()
    ->select([
        'customer_id',
        'data' => $customersTable->getConnection()->quote('test')
    ])
    ->where(['email' => 'username@example']);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Selecting Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-data)**

Comment: Thank you Oliver!